# Facebook log in on Android device not working, but works in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

I'm creating an Android app which allows the user to log in via facebook

This is working fine when I run the app on my emulator, but when I test it on my mobile device, I receive the following:

> 10-30 16:50:43.784 24503-24503/com.example.user.sociall2 I/chromium:
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source:
>   data:text/html,chromewebdata (0)
>
> 10-30 16:50:43.798 24503-24503/com.example.user.sociall2
>   D/logOutput: FBLogInError: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Can anybody tell me why and how I can solve this?

Comment: Which sdk are you using? JavaScript or Android?

Comment: sorry should have said - Android

Comment: Just to make sure, are you sure your internet connection is working propely on this device? I'm asking because these errors sometimes stem from connection problems

Comment: You're absolutely right, it was an internet connection problem, thank you so much for helping me realise it was that

Comment: Np, good luck with your development

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ensure you're connected to the internet everyone..

Answer (score 2):

if your internet provider (Wifi) restricting to use facebook.
it will throw the same error.

I spent almost some hours to identify it.

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>                                                    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult
>   >
>   >
>   >
>
> > onError: 
> >                                                  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
> >                                                      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:190)
> >                                                      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:159)
> >                                                      at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)

so check facebook in your browser first.

Answer (score 0):

Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): The server could not be found.

I hope this work for you:

- Click Start =>Run, type in CMD, press OK.
- Copy and paste this into the Command prompt:
- netsh winsock reset catalog
- Press Enter
- Then copy and paste this in:
- netsh int ip reset reset.log
- Press Enter.
- When finished restart your computer.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oCUYZsG8VJU

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following code to perform facebook login using facebook sdk 4.7 [facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33584208/3959610)

Comment: I know how to log in using facebook, think you misunderstood my question - I've solved it now, thanks anyway :)